# Webview doesn't have setDownloadListener()?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I had a problem with downloading through WebView, and found this code:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Problem is, my WebView doesn't have the function setDownladListener()... I also saw that they use WebView.loadUrl(), and I don't have this as well, I have WebView.Source... 
Why is my webview different? And how do I change it to that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi bro, Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks!

Comment: Okey , if answer be helpful, thanks for marking it. And you can show your solution in answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Android [WebView.SetDownloadListener()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.SetDownloadListener/p/Android.Webkit.IDownloadListener/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Android.Webkit.WebView webView;` first in your code.

Init **webView** :

```
webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
webView.LoadUrl("https://www.xamarin.com/university");
webView.SetDownloadListener(new downloadListener());
```

This need create a custom HttpClient (**HelloWebViewClient**),here has `LoadUrl` method:

```
public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    // For API level 24 and later
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And if want to **SetDownloadListener** , need to create `IDownloadListener` :

```
public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
{
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));

    request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VisibilityVisibleNotifyCompleted);
    request.SetTitle("Download finish");
    request.SetAllowedOverMetered(true);
    request.SetVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.SetAllowedOverRoaming(true);

    //this file path need dynamic request permission
    //String fileName = URLUtil.GuessFileName(url, contentDisposition, "Downloadfile");
    //request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("Download").ToString() , fileName);

    DownloadManager downloadManager = DownloadManager.FromContext(this);
    long downloadId = downloadManager.Enqueue(request);

}
```